# How to set specific text input be not required to fill in

Tags: javascript, html

First of all i'm a newbie of programming . I want to create a mini project  using multiform. I use example from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp but i wonder how to set specific text input be not required to fill in for proceed the process of submit the data. Sorry for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code from W3S but the validation code is changed.

If you look in the code you will find commented fields with many `!!!` this is the validator

**EDIT:**

Currently the field for "Last name" i added an attribute `data="noverify"` Currently, any field that has this attribute will not be required.

In this example: First name is **required**. A Last name is **NOT required**!

Add this attribute `data="noverify"` for all fields you want NOT to be required!

This check `y[i].getAttribute('data') !== "noverify"` is made below in the code to skip the fields with `data="noverify"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    #regForm {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        margin: 100px auto;
        font-family: Raleway;
        padding: 40px;
        width: 70%;
        min-width: 300px;
    }

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }

    input {
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: Raleway;
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    }

    /* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
    input.invalid {
        background-color: #ffdddd;
    }

    /* Hide all steps by default: */
    .tab {
        display: none;
    }

    button {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: #ffffff;
        border: none;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: Raleway;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    button:hover {
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    #prevBtn {
        background-color: #bbbbbb;
    }

    /* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
    .step {
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
        margin: 0 2px;
        background-color: #bbbbbb;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .step.active {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    /* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
    .step.finish {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
        <h1>Register:</h1>
        <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
        <div class="tab">Name:
            <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
            <p><input data="noverify" placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">Contact Info:
            <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>
            <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">Birthday:
            <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd"></p>
            <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" name="nn"></p>
            <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="yyyy"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">Login Info:
            <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname"></p>
            <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword" type="password"></p>
        </div>
        <div style="overflow:auto;">
            <div style="float:right;">
                <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
                <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
        <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
            <span class="step"></span>
            <span class="step"></span>
            <span class="step"></span>
            <span class="step"></span>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
        showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

        function showTab(n) {
            // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
            x[n].style.display = "block";
            //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
            if (n == 0) {
                document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
            }
            if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
                document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
            }
            //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
            fixStepIndicator(n)
        }

        function nextPrev(n) {
            // This function will figure out which tab to display
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
            // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
            if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
            // Hide the current tab:
            x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
            // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
            currentTab = currentTab + n;
            // if you have reached the end of the form...
            if (currentTab >= x.length) {
                // ... the form gets submitted:
                document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
                return false;
            }
            // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
            showTab(currentTab);
        }

        function validateForm() {
            // This function deals with validation of the form fields
            var x, y, i, valid = true;


            // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

            x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
            y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
            // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
            for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {

                if (y[i].getAttribute('data') !== "noverify") {
                    // If a field is empty...
                    if (y[i].value == "") {
                        // add an "invalid" class to the field:
                        y[i].className += " invalid";
                        // and set the current valid status to false
                        valid = false;
                    }
                }

            }
            // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:

            // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


            if (valid) {
                document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
            }
            return valid; // return the valid status
        }

        function fixStepIndicator(n) {
            // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
            var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
            x[n].className += " active";
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but how about  allows only one input form not  to be required and not all ? Thanks

Comment: See my example! First name is required. A Last name is NOT required!

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful! You can mark this post as Accepted Answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use value for set default text value

```html
<div class="tab">Name:
  <p><input placeholder="First name..." value="One" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  <p><input placeholder="Last name..." value="Two" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: i was thinking about a one text form that user have optional to fill in or not. just one input and other form is required but in the same form.Thanks